# Query to exclude rows whose ID is listed in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do an optimized query to do the following, even though it sounds simple.

Suppose I have a table called promo (one column: ID), and another table called promo_has_been_displayed_to_user (two columns: promo_id and user_id, and promo_id is a foreign key referencing promo.ID).  I want a query that will return all the rows in promo whose ID field is NOT mentioned in any row in promo_has_been_displayed_to_user where the promo_has_been_displayed_to_user.user_id field is set to 45. Let's say I have indexes on all fields.

(The idea is that I have a database of promotional ads and a database of users, and each time I show an ad to a user, I store in promo_has_been_displayed_to_user that it has been shown to them.  Now I want to find a new ad that has not been displayed to user 45.)

It seems the theoretically optimal way to do this would be the following:

1) Get a subset of promo_has_been_displayed_to_user where user_id=45, and in that subset, maintain the index on the user_id field. 2) For each row in promo, take the ID and look it up in the subset generated in step 1, on the indexed promo_id field. 3) Return all the rows in promo where you didn't find a match in step 2.

But how do I structure a query that reflects that?

Now, I have at least two queries that will return the right answer (I have verified with test data); the problem is that I don't think they will run optimally, for the following reasons:

1)

```
select * from promo
where ID not in (select promo_id from promo_has_been_displayed_to_user
                 where user_id=45)
```

The trouble with this query is that once you have the list of IDs returned by "select promo_id from promo_has_been_displayed_to_user where user_id=45", I assume it's just a *list* (without an index onit), and that the "not in" check is implemented by just checking that list one at a time.  If the subset of promo_has_been_displayed_to_user where user_id=45 turns out to be huge, then for each row in promo, we have to search through a huge list with no index on it.

2)

```
select * from promo p
where not exists (select * from promo_has_been_displayed_to_user
                  where promo_id = p.ID and user_id=45)
```

This time, we are doing the lookup on the indexed promo_id field.  However, for every row in promo, I'm querying the entire promo_has_been_displayed_to_user table.  This is wasteful if there's only a small subset of promo_has_been_displayed_to_user where user_id=45.

Is there a single query that will combine the best of both worlds -- I first whittle down promo_has_been_displayed_to_user to the subset where user_id=45, and then for each row in promo, I do an indexed lookup on promo_id to see if there's a matching row in the subset?

(This is MySQL 5.0.95, although this sounds like something that isn't database-server-specific.)

Comment: Try a left join instead. Will probably execute faster on MySQL.

Comment: It's a simple exclusion join

Answer (score 15):

You cannot do this with an inner join.  What you need to do is an antijoin.  Usually this is most easily done using a query like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM A WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM B);
```

That is the basic syntax of an antojoin in SQL.

An alternative way to do this however is to turn a LEFT JOIN into an antijoin and on some databases this performs better:

```
SELECT A.* 
  FROM A
  LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
 WHERE A.id IS NOT NULL AND B.id IS NULL;
```

This turns out to be equivalent and some databases can optimize it better.

Comment: The EXCEPT keyword is also an option. Like this : `SELECT id FROM A EXCEPT SELECT id FROM B` With this however you have to select the same column types in both queries.

Comment: @iPhantomGuy, does MySQL support EXCEPT? Besides, OP selects all columns from A, and B is maybe not fully compatible.

Comment: Just found out that MySQL does not support EXCEPT.

Comment: I also think EXCEPT is often a pain to optimize

Comment: The reason I wanted to avoid the "NOT IN" syntax was because I assumed the query optimizer would search the "IN" list one at a time instead of doing an optimized lookup.

However, based on the pointers provided here, I was able to find how to do it using a left join with a subquery.  For posterity, the query that works is:

    select * from promo left join (select * from promo_has_been_displayed_to_user where user_id=45) as tsubset ON pro
mo.ID=tsubset.promo_id WHERE promo_id IS NULL;

Comment: why the inline view?  See my second example which I think can be more readily optimized.

Comment: Wonderful answer, love when specific questions like this get appropriately vague answers to make it useful to everyone 